# discord.py - Can't send message to channel in other guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
async def sendmessage(ctx, channelID=None, content=None):
  if channelID == None:
      print("ERROR: NSB01")
  else:
     await bot.get_channel(channelID).send(content)
```

Can't seem to send a message to a channel in other server/guild... The bot is present in both server (the one where the user issues a command and the one where the target channel is in)

no errors whatsoever in the console too. Any help or suggestion are appreciated

Comment: I asume that the `context manager (ctx)` is aware about the guild / user, which called a command. Because of that I would say it is not possible to send a message in another discord, if the call was made in the the other one

Comment: Might be it. However, it worked when I took the channel id of a message(trough the on_message event), storing it in a global variable and then using it from another command issued from another server.

```@bot.command()
async def reply(ctx, args):
 
 await bot.get_channel(GLOBALID.channel.id).send(args)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do something like this:

```py
@bot.command()
async def sendmessage(ctx, channelID: int = None, content=None):
  if channelID is None:
      print("ERROR: NSB01")
  else:
     await bot.get_channel(channelID).send(content)
```

Or you can fetch a channel:

```py
channel = await bot.fetch_channel(channelID)
await channel.send(content)
```